# HRGN equivalent on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, winapi

In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), region is defined as following

> A region is a rectangle, polygon, or ellipse (or a combination of two or more of these shapes) that can be filled, painted, inverted, framed, and used to perform hit testing (testing for the cursor location).

So, what is equivalent of region on Mac OS X which also supports the operations of HRGN such as combining region, taking XOR of the regions etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly, a Bézier path. A Bézier path can describe pretty much any shape, and you can fill, stroke, and concatenate them.

No XOR, although winding rules can sometimes produce the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is one other option: [HIShape](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/HIShape_Reference/).

The disadvantage over Bézier paths: A shape can only contain rectangles. You can forget about ellipses and arbitrary polygons.

The advantage: You can effect XOR by taking the union of both differences, or the difference of the intersection from the union.

You can draw with a shape by [replacing a context's path with it](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/HIShape_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/HIShapeReplacePathInCGContext) and then filling and/or stroking as normal.